# Assembly Version Conflicts with What is Already Bound

Tags: silverlight, assemblies, appdomain, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm running Microsoft LightSwitch Beta 1 and have been creating an application which has been going great, but then I tried debugging after making a few minor changes and received the following error:

> "Could not load file or assembly
>   'SW_Resources.Commom, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. The
>   requested assembly version conflicts
>   with what is already bound in the app
>   domain or specified in the manifest.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131053)"

I've tried emptying my cache in Firefox and IE but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

I did discover if I right-clicked on the Solution and changed the version from 0.1 to 1.0 then it works fine. I had changed it to 0.1 b/c I wanted to reflect that it wasn't a release version...any thoughts on how to get around this issue the right way?